# Adding an extra field to the join table in has_many through association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my app I have jobs which can have a review after completion. Review table is pre-filled with predefined values. Manager should select a checkboxes of all the reviews she want's to add to the Job.

I have a has_many :through association with extra column which is an extra association in the join table:

```
class Job < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :job_reviews, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :reviews, through: :job_reviews

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :job_reviews, allow_destroy: true, reject_if: :all_blank
end

class Review < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :job_reviews, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :jobs, through: :job_reviews
end

class JobReview < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :job
  belongs_to :review
  belongs_to :user
end
```

In the view i have such a form:

```
  = simple_form_for @job do |f|
    = f.association :reviews, collection: Review.all, as: :check_boxes, include_hidden: false, label: false
    = f.input :user_id, input_html: {value: current_user.id}
    = f.button :submit, class: 'btn btn-success'
```

and the controller looks like this:

```
  def job_params
    params.require(:job).permit(:user_id, review_ids: [])
  end
```

When i run the code these are the params that are being processed:

```
<ActionController::Parameters {"user_id"=>"dfd24578-5asa-4143-b209-d13cb419af30", "review_ids"=>["453852c5-45f0-4f67-a41c-e7e50dab711a", "a1303a62-fbef-5asa-95a0-a3ffa0b7616c"]} permitted: true>
```

the create method in the controller:

```
  def create   
    respond_to do |format|
      if @job.update(job_params)
        format.js
      else
        format.js { render :js=>"alert('#{@job.errors.full_messages }');" }
      end
    end
  end
```

and this is the error i get:

```
INSERT INTO "job_reviews" ("uuid", "review_id", "job_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "uuid"  [["id", "dfd24578-5asa-42b8-807c-38be1036bcf5"], ["review_id", "a1303a62-fbef-5asa-95a0-a3ffa0b7616c"], ["job_id", "cb7eba6e-95a0-45f0-81f2-490d1c80ee07"], ["created_at", "2019-06-13 12:04:08.581557"], ["updated_at", "2019-06-13 12:04:08.581557"]]
   (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
ActiveRecord::NotNullViolation: PG::NotNullViolation: ERROR:  null value in column "user_id" violates not-null constraint
```

Comment: It seems you are not passing `user_id` param. Can you post the permitted parameters from controller and the generated HTML form?

Comment: Show the `create` method in the controller

Comment: @iGian the permitted params are already there.

Comment: @chumakoff i added the create method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all:

- there is a mistake in the `JobReview` model. Replace `belongs_to :job_review` with `belongs_to :review`
- the `job_review_params` method should be renamed to `job_params` as it is in fact a `Job` object that you assign params to.

---

When you assign `reviews` to a `job` passing the `review_ids` parameter, Rails tries to automatically create the `job_reviews` association. It fails because Rails can't automatically calculate the `user_id` value and it is not passed properly.

Although you have the `user_id` parameter in the form, it is passed as `job`'s attribute. Rails doesn't know what to do with it.

One of the ways to solve the problem is to assign `reviews` to a `job` manually:

```
job_params[:review_ids].each do |review_id|
  @job.job_reviews.build(review_id: review_id, user_id: current_user.id)
end

@job.save
```

In this case you don't have to send `user_id` through the form because it is available in the controller:

```
= simple_form_for @job do |f|
  = f.association :reviews, collection: Review.all, as: :check_boxes, include_hidden: false, label: false
  = f.button :submit, class: 'btn btn-success'
```

Comment: I fixed the mistakes (these happened as I was typing the question here but in the project, they are correct, thanks anyway) 

I actually did something similar to your answer in my project but this has a problem when I want to update the form then it tries to put all the selected back in the db again without checking if they are in the db already. I solved it by checking which ones need to be added or deleted before saving. 

It works but I was hoping for a cleaner solution. Maybe there is no cleaner way!